# Ansible logstash installation

Tags: ansible, logstash

I am trying to install Logstash using Ansible on RHEL 7.
After installation, I am not able to start the logstash service. I get `service not found` error.I searched online and found the below command.

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/system-install /etc/logstash/startup.options systemd
```

After which, logstash service started.

I did as below in my playbook just above the systemd command. But it is not idempotent. The first task is being run every time.
I have two questions here.
1. Other than using shell is there any way to achieve this?
2. What `when` condition can I put in this task to make it idempotent. If I check the service status and put the status in when condition, then I need to write it again at the end to ensure status(duplicate tasks). 
Or else I just need to run this command only the first time it is run on this server. Is that possible?
Please advice.

```
    - name: generate logstash.service file for systemd
      shell: /usr/share/logstash/bin/system-install /etc/logstash/startup.options systemd

    - name: Enable and restart logstash.service
      systemd:
       name: logstash.service
       enabled: yes
       state: restarted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to execute some script - you can use `shell` or `command`. Otherwise you can generate systemd service yourself
2. You don't need to use `when` to do that, you can use `creates` keyword in shell task.

Assuming your unit file gets created in /etc/systemd/system/logstash.service

You should write your first task as

```
 - name: generate logstash.service file for systemd
   shell: /usr/share/logstash/bin/system-install /etc/logstash/startup.options systemd
   creates: /etc/systemd/system/logstash.service
```

If ansible finds that this file exists next time - it won't run script again.

The other method is to template /etc/logstash/startup.options and run generate service task only if your template has changed.

Comment: Is there any ansible module for /usr/share/logstash/bin/system-install instead of using shell command

Comment: @smily i don't think so. If you are trying to deploy ELK stack using ansible - you might want to check Ansible Galaxy for existing roles, https://galaxy.ansible.com/search?deprecated=false&keywords=logstash&order_by=-relevance&page=1

Comment: thanks, yes I used the role initially. But the service didnt start and I had to update code with this workaround